# How can I use CodeIgniter's active record (or models) object in a command line script?

Tags: codeigniter

Title pretty much sums it up. I'd like to write a script to import some data from a third party. Is there any way I can get either an instance of CodeIgniter's Active Record class, or of a particular model inside of an a script that can be run from the command line?

Comment: are you saying you want to run a CI app from command line? Please clarify...

Comment: i am trying to write a script to import some data into a CI application via the command line. I figured this would be made a lot easier if I could use some of CodeIgniter's already built-in functionality, such as the active record class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have your CodeIgnited application inside `ignited/`, you have your command line script running in `cli/`. Here is your folder layout:

```
ignited/
    application/
    system/
    index.php
cli/
    mycli.php
```

Now you want `cli/mycli.php` to use some model from `ignited/`

First, you should do something with your `ignited` app:

1. Modify your default controller (which is set in `ignited/application/config/routes.php`). For example `ignited/application/controllers/welcome.php`:

   ```
   class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

       public function index()
       {
           $this->load->view('welcome_message');
       }
   }
   ```

   add these code:

   ```
   if ($this->input->is_cli_request())
   {
       return;
   }
   ```

   so it would look like:

   ```
   class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

       public function index()
       {
           if ($this->input->is_cli_request())
           {
               return;
           }
           $this->load->view('welcome_message');
       }
   }
   ```
2. For testing, I created a test model `ignited/application/models/do_nothing_model.php`:

   ```
   class Do_nothing_model extends CI_Model {

       public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
       }

       public function do_nothing()
       {
           return "Do nothing";
       }

   }
   ```

OK! Now try this in `cli/mycli.php`:

```
require_once('../ignited/index.php');

$ci =& get_instance();

$ci->load->model('do_nothing_model');
echo $ci->do_nothing_model->do_nothing();
```

***Drawback***: unable to run the default action of your default controller in command line

**UPDATE 2012-06-08**: from [CodeIgniter Wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Calling_CI_models_from_outside_script)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but if you just need to run CI from CLI, here is the userguide reference:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

To clarify, you don't need it web facing, just setup your app and run the commands you need (controller method input):

```
$ php index.php tools message "John Smith"
```

that example would run the primary `index.php` file for CI, then the `tools` controller and method `message`, "John Smith" is your input to message (could be a file reference that is local on the machine for your file import).

Comment: this could work, but it seems to me that this still requires creating a public-facing controller, which i'd like to avoid if at all possible

Comment: No you don't need it public facing, just put it into a folder and run... PHP can be run web/cli no matter what framework